# 4 to 16 decoder made by two 3 to 8 decoders not working properly

Tags: decoder, function

I have a function f(x,y,z,w)=x.y.z+ y’.z’+x’.w’ and I need to make a circuit using two 3 to 8 decoders, an inverter, an or gate with as many inputs as we want (I use two because I need a 9 input one and on DEEDS I found up to 8) and up to 16 and gates (???). So far I've made this circuit based on the fact that f= Σ(0,1,2,4,6,8,9,14,15).
[image: Logic circuit]

I don't seem to figure out where the AND gates go. Also, this circuit is not working properly as it returns 0 when y and z are 1 which, by the truth table returns 1. I provide the truth table below.
[image: Truth table of f]

Why is this happening? Aren't the outputs of the decoders the minterms of the function? (e.g. D0= x'y'z'w')
Also, any suggestion about the AND gates and the solution? No need for the full solution just some help to guide me.

Comment: Check your labeling of the inputs vs. your truth table.

Comment: you do not have any AND gates in your circuit

Comment: Really. As Spehro says, check your wiring.

Comment: You say nothing about being allowed to use ORs, yet you *do* have these.

Comment: Greatly sorry, forgot to add that!

Comment: This is a duplicated recurring academic question

Answer (score 2):

With what you have in the truth table and what you have wired in the output (right) side of the 3:8 decoders, the input (left) side of the decoders should look like this:

> y --> A2
>
> z --> A1
>
> w --> A0

You mixed the LSB of input with MSB.

Comment: Thank you! That helped, I wasn't quite aware of this. Do you have any clue how I could use the AND gates in this circuit?

Comment: AND gates are unnecessary.

Comment: Please make the fixes MITU RAJ suggests

Comment: With the suggestions it works smoothly however I got puzzled as my instructor suggested to use and gates as well. Probably I misunderstood him or something! Thank you again!

Comment: well you can substitute OR gate with NAND gate equivalent. And then substitute all NANDs with ANDs and NOTs .... Hm but tiring job :P

Comment: AND gates would replace the decoder, as that it what it is... 8 3-input AND gates per decoder.  Maybe he mentioned it as an option to a decoder or just didn't tell you why he mentioned them(?)  Anyway, seems you got it now.

Comment: ^^ with inverters, thus the inverters he mentioned too.

Comment: Yeah as I mentioned above I could use only one inverter. :'( else representing the decoder with and gates would be a viable strategy.